# Appending a Font-Awesome icon to an H1 element using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, font-awesome

I am trying to dynamically append an FA icon to an `<h1>` tag using JQuery. The icon does get appended; however, it doesn't render on display. My JQuery snippet is a ridiculously simple and straightforward one:

```
function pronounce() {  
  $('h1.source-text').append('<i class="icon-volume-up pronounce"></i>');
};
```

The above function is called once a certain condition (as outlined in another script) checks out. The script is not wrong because I can see the appended FA icon in my Web Inspector:

[image]

What could be going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FontsAwesome uses the following syntax:

```
<i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>
```

Source: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/volume-up/

Comment: I got my link from http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/3.2.1/icon/volume-up/. Is that a deprecated one then?

Comment: Correct. They have a warning at the top of the home page of that version that states `Heads up! These docs are for v3.2.1, which is no longer officially supported. Check out the latest version of Font Awesome!` which links to http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/

Answer (score 2):

If you're using this [font-awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) I think the class for the `<i>` should be `fa fa-volume-up` so your entire `<i>` will become:

```
<i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>
```

Find all the classes and icons [here](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/)

Hope this helps!